# Remove back bar button title from container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

I need empty back button title, so using category method as:

```
-(void)removeBackButtonTitle
{
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
}
```

But I have a situation where I need to take `Container View` and some viewcontroller as child view controller and its view as a subview. Now upon navigation from this view, back button title is not setting to empty.

Comment: guys, its not like normal navigation from one to next viewcontroller, its from `container view` of one to next viewcontroller.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the following code to your viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear..

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

This will remove **Back** text from that Back button. Also here you can set your own title as you desire.

---

@preetam ..  for your case, every view controller has its lifecycle methods viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear.

Also, you are using Default navigation bar/Custom NavigationBar as you shown in screenshot.

If you're using Default, then your answer is given above. otherwise, you can remove the **Back** text in Storyboard itself.

Hope it helps..

Comment: can you show your code ? Update the navigating code.

Comment: posted in question..using this before pushing the viewcontroller

Comment: For pushing your viewcontroller, you'll need one navigationcontroller. So set the above code for that navigationcontroller. Thats it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and set setTitle to blank @"":

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@""]; //make Title for backBarbutton to blank
```

It works for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following lines of code in the (previous) view controllers where you don't want to display back button title.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"Your Title";
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.title = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3 you can use this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
  backItem.title = ""
  navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below line of code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:nil
                                action:nil];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:newBackButton, nil];
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Didn't you read in question about in container view this solution wont work?